# Eject Windows 7 Installation DVD 1, during boot camp install on MacBook Pro (Intel Based)

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have 2 DVD's for installing Windows. The 1st DVD contains part of the Windows 7 installation and then the DVD 2 has to be inserted. Now, when I try to install Win7 on my MacBook Pro using Boot Camp Assistant, it starts Windows and initiates the steps to copy the files (1st step in the installation).

After some time, it pops up a window asking for the 2nd DVD to be inserted. But I have not been able to find a way to eject the 1st DVD and insert the second without rebooting the system, which fails my Windows 7 installation.

Can anyone help out with the same?

Comment: What kind of windows 7 ships on two DVDs?

Comment: @Max Ried: This is Windows 7 Professional, with Language Packs.

Comment: Isn't it possible to install the language packs afterwards?

Comment: I never did this. What kind of dialog asks for the next disk? Is it a "Retry"-"Cancel"-dialog or is it a "Choose folder" one?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't eject a CD/DVD during Boot Camp install. You can only eject it:

- during boot (holding down the trackpad button)
- while running OS X or recovery
- while running Windows with Boot Camp drivers installed

The workaround is to copy the contents of the second DVD to a flash stick, insert that into an USB port **BEFORE** installation begin and, when asked for the second DVD, provide the path to the flash stick.

Comment: where do I provide the path? Before the installation begins? As once it begins and I get that pop-up, I am unable to proceed and give any path or anything else! Only "OK" or "CANCEL" :-(

Comment: @gagneet - my experience with multi-disk Windows installers stops at Win 3.11 and floppies. Though I think that after clicking ok with disc 1 in, it should let you choose a location, pretty much the same way it does when it doesn't find a driver.

Answer (score -1):

Type E:\ and it will see the USB flash stick.